# how to pass information from one jsp page to other jsp page

Tags: java, jsp

i have retrieved some data in a jsp page1.i've given link of page2 in page1.i want that when i click the link the data is displayed on page2.how to do that???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Options:

1. Use session
2. Use URL params
3. Use POST form
4. Use a cookie

See http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/java/Servlet-Tutorial/Servlet-Tutorial-Session-Tracking.html for a tutorial on sessions.